# Woocommerce user registration post request

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, user-registration

I have setup Woocommerce to automatically register a new customer when the order is completed.

Now I want to send the password and other things that has been generated to a third party using a API POST request to create the same user account.

Things I need to send from the Woocommerce generated account:

- Email address (used for email and login on third party website)
- First name
- Last name
- Password (Needs to be unhashed, same as used in new account email)

Can someone show me an example how to get this done? Or point me in to the right direction? I just can't find anything to start with.

I thought by adding Curl to the Woocommerce thank you page webhook. But this won't send the password unhashed, it just stay blank.

Hope someone knows an easy way to get this done.

Thanks!

---

**Latest UPDATE: CODE USING IN MY FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
class NewCustomerRegistration
{
    private $credentials;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Use PHP_INT_MAX so that it is the last filter run on this data
        // in case there are other filter changing the password, for example
        add_filter(
            'woocommerce_new_customer_data',
            [$this, 'when_user_is_created'],
            1,
            PHP_INT_MAX
        );
        add_action('woocommerce_new_customer', [$this, 'when_customer_is_created']);
    }

    public function when_user_is_created($customerData)
    {
        $this->credentials = [
            'email'     => $customerData['user_email'],
            'password'  => $customerData['user_pass'],

        ];

        return $customerData;
    }

    public function when_customer_is_created($customerId)
    {
        $customer = get_userdata($customerId);

        /**
         * Perform the required actions with collected data
         *
         * Email: $this->credentials['email']
         * Password: $this->credentials['password']
         * First Name: $customer->first_name
         * Last Name: $customer->last_name
         */

    // Testing sending email function
    $subject = "Test Email with data";
    $email   = "info@mydomain.com";

    $message  = "Hello, {$customer->first_name}\n\n";
    $message .= "Here are your login details for {$customer->first_name} {$customer->last_name}\n\n";
    $message .= "Your company is: {$customer->company}\n\n";
    $message .= "Your username is: {$this->credentials['email']}\n\n";    
    $message .= "Your password is: {$this->credentials['password']}\n\n";
    $message .= "Your email is: {$this->credentials['email']}\n\n";
    $message .= "Your role is: {$customer->role}\n\n";

    $headers = array();

    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function( $content_type ) {return 'text/html';});
    $headers[] = 'From: My Wordpress Website <info@mydomain.com>'."\r\n";
    wp_mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers);

   // Reset content-type to avoid conflicts
   remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is that generated data?

Comment: It’s from Woocommerce when an order is placed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the combining the actions [`woocommerce_created_customer`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_create_new_customer.html#101-114) (for email and password) and [`woocommerce_new_customer`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Customer_Data_Store.html#124) (for other customer details) could do the job for you.

My thinking is that you could do something like..

```
class NewCustomerRegistration
{
    private $credentials;

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', [$this, 'when_user_is_created']);
        add_action('woocommerce_new_customer', [$this, 'when_customer_is_created']);
    }

    public function when_user_is_created($customerId, $customerData)
    {
        $this->credentials = [
            'email'     => $customerData['user_email'],
            'password'  => $customerData['user_pass'],
        ];
    }

    public function when_customer_is_created($customerId)
    {
        $customer = get_userdata($customerId);

        /**
         * Send email with collected data
         *
         * Email: $this->credentials['email']
         * Password: $this->credentials['password']
         * First Name: $customer->first_name
         * Last Name: $customer->last_name
         */
        wp_mail(...);
    }
}
```

***NOTE*** You should probably clear the credentials after sending so that, if the `woocommerce_new_customer` action is called with a different user for some reason, the credentials aren't sent out to a different user. You should probably add some error checks in too, just for your own sanity.

**UPDATE**

As you are getting an error with the `woocommerce_created_customer` action you might get better results listening for the `woocommerce_new_customer_data` filter.

```
class NewCustomerRegistration
{
    private $credentials;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Use PHP_INT_MAX so that it is the last filter run on this data
        // in case there are other filter changing the password, for example
        add_filter(
            'woocommerce_new_customer_data',
            [$this, 'when_user_is_created'],
            1,
            PHP_INT_MAX
        );
        add_action('woocommerce_new_customer', [$this, 'when_customer_is_created']);
    }

    public function when_user_is_created($customerData)
    {
        $this->credentials = [
            'email'     => $customerData['user_email'],
            'password'  => $customerData['user_pass'],
        ];

        return $customerData;
    }

    public function when_customer_is_created($customerId)
    {
        $customer = get_userdata($customerId);

        /**
         * Perform the required actions with collected data
         *
         * Email: $this->credentials['email']
         * Password: $this->credentials['password']
         * First Name: $customer->first_name
         * Last Name: $customer->last_name
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And sorry I was not clear enough. I mean I need to send the information to a third party system and create the user with their API. So then I would need to replace the last bit with a curl? To make a post request with the third party api right?

Comment: The fields are all there for you to use so you can use it however you need to, if the third party recommends/demonstrates using CURL then that would probably be the easiest.

Comment: Thank you! After adding it to my functions.php nothing is being send? I'm just testing this using wp_mail to see if I'm getting the right things. Also enabled logging, but it not showing any errors or warnings. Hope you can help me out.
@qooplmao

Comment: Are you instantiating the class anywhere? If not you should add `new NewCustomerRegistration();` under the class, otherwise it's never actually being called meaning that the action listeners are never being added.

Comment: When I add it under the class (at the end) It will show me the following error: **PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function NewCustomerRegistration::when_user_is_created(), 1 is passed and exactly 2 expected**  Any ideas lol? Spend hours searching, but can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Which version of WooCommerce are you using? Using the `woocommerce_new_customer_data` filter might be better for you. I'll update.

Comment: thanks! I’m using Woocommerce 3.4.5. Only now it’s not sending the email I would like to get? Please see my code above, I’m using now in functions.php. Am I missing anything? Ps: no errors or warnings!

Comment: any idea? Why the email is not being send? Just want to test it, hope you can help me.

Comment: Hope someone can still help me with this

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/56338792/8631622 Please look into this problem. I did everything I could. But I could not solve this problem @qooplmao